# OpenSSL, Обход вопроса

Tags: linux, openssl

Есть задача автоматизировать шифрование текста через Openssl.
Команда:

```
echo -n "nicework" | openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -a -salt
```

Пробовали добавить -passin 'pass:??????????????'(Вместо ? разумеется пароль), не работает, -passout тоже. Подскажите, как обойти данную проблему и сделать что бы OpenSSL не спрашивал пароль а уже знал его из аргумента? ну или хоть как то, нужно использовать в скрипте full-auto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
echo -n "nicework" | openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -a -salt -k <password>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!